# C++ c string separation with a ' '

Tags: c++

I am rather new to c++ and I am taking my first course on it. I need to make a program that accepts input from the user like so "HelloHowAreYouToday" and at each capital letter turn it into a lower case letter and split apart the c string to look like this "Hello how are you today". Here is my code so far.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <iomanip>
#include <cmath>
#include <string>

using namespace std;

int main()
{
char sentence[100];
int size;

cout << "Enter a sentence with no spaces, make first letter in each word an upper case: ";
cin.getline(sentence, 100);

size = strlen(sentence);

char * manipSent = new char[size + 1];

for (int i = 1; i < size + 1; i++)
{
    if (sentence[i] >= 'A' && sentence[i] <= 'Z')
    {
        manipSent[i] = ' ';
        manipSent[i] = tolower(sentence[i]);
    }
    else;
        manipSent[i] = tolower(sentence[i]);

}
manipSent[0] = sentence[0];

manipSent[size] = NULL;

cout << endl;
cout << "Original Sentence: " << sentence << endl;
cout << endl;
cout << "Altered Sentence:  " << manipSent << endl;

delete[] manipSent;

return 0;
}
```

The issue I am having is splitting the words up, the out put looks like "Hellohowareyoutoday" but when I try to add a space in between the words the first letter in each word gets erased. Any input would be appreciated.

Comment: You're not incrementing `i` after writing the space, so you immediately write over it. And your buffer will be too small since you're not taking spaces into account when allocating it. Use `std::string` instead.

Comment: Step 1: Use `std::string` instead of a char buffer.  Step 2) Insert a space.  Step 3) ??? Step 4) Profit.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is because whenever you put a space in your string, you immediately overwrite it by the lowercase version of the letter. If you write multiple values to one space, only the last value remains. This is why you don't have any spaces in your resulting string.

```
    manipSent[i] = ' ';                  /* manipSent is now a space */
    manipSent[i] = tolower(sentence[i]); /* overwrite manipSent[i]   */
```

In order to do what you are trying to do, you need another variable besides `i` to keep track of where you are writing into `manipSent`. Look at the code below - I've created a new variable `j` that keeps up with `i` when you're copying characters, but if you add a space, it gets incremented again to deal with the fact that the new string is going to be larger than the old one.

```
for (int i = 1, j = 1; i < size + 1; i++, j++)
{
    if (sentence[i] >= 'A' && sentence[i] <= 'Z')
    {
        manipSent[j] = ' ';
        j++;
        manipSent[j] = tolower(sentence[i]);
    }
    else;
        manipSent[j] = tolower(sentence[i]);  

}
```

It is important to remember that `manipSent` will be longer than `sentence` - in fact, it will be up to twice as long, so make sure you make `manipSent` bigger before you try adding spaces to it.